# How to replace user inputted ^ with **?

Tags: python, replace, lambda

Hey so I guess I will start with my code then go into my problem:

```
def trapezoidal(a, b, deltax, func = None):

func = lambda x: (raw_input("Enter a function to have a trapezoidal approximation taken     
of. Enter it in the form a*x^m + b*x^n + c*x, a*x^m +c, etc. (ex. 3*x^3 + 4*x^2...) ")

h = float(b - a) / deltax  
s = 0.0                 
s += func(a)/2.0
for i in range(1, deltax):
    s += func(a + i*h)
s += func(b)/2.0
return s * h
```

Basically I am trying to make this user friendly. What I need to do is replace the ^ in a raw_input to ** so a lambda can evaluate it. Ultimately I want to plug in values for a, b, and delta x, press enter, enter the function using close to normal notation (using ^ instead of **). I know this may seem silly and pointless but user friendliness is a must. I would even like to get rid of having to make the user put in a * between the coefficient and the variable ((preferably 3x^2 would be evaluated as 3*x**2) then plugged into the lambda and then the rest of it run. I realize I can simply put in

```
def trapezoidal(a, b, deltax, func):

h = float(b - a) / deltax  
s = 0.0                 
s += func(a)/2.0
for i in range(1, deltax):
    s += func(a + i*h)
s += func(b)/2.0
return s * h

trapezoidal(5, 10, 100, lambda x: 3*x**2 + 2*x)
```

and it be evaluated fine. But that is not user friendly.

Comment: This looks like Python code (I added the tag) but the indentation is off and you have unpaired parentheses. Please edit your code to be syntactically valid before asking others to look at it.

Comment: The function argument `func` gets overwritten right at the start, so is currently useless. Maybe you should only request input if it's unset? Or have the caller do the prompting; functions with interactive calls are often not a very good design.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem:

```
def trapezoidal(a, b, deltax, func = None):

#first we find the height using our range divided by deltax

h = float(b - a) / deltax  

'''
 next we find start to calculate the sum; set s to 0 to make it start at 0
we divide func(a) by two, because of the area of trapezoid 1/2(b1 + b2)h
next use a for loop to evaluate the b1 + b2
s is basically the 1/2(b1 + b2), then we multiply it by h, the height.
tr '''   
s = 0.0                 
s += func(a)/2.0
for i in range(1, deltax):
    s += func(a + i*h)
s += func(b)/2.0
return s * h

     '''
    next we are going to get our values for a, b, and deltax
    we must use eval(func) to use the lambda x:.
    it then runs through trapezoidal()
    '''
def userexp():
    a = int(raw_input("Enter your a "))
    b = int(raw_input("enter your b "))
    deltax = int(raw_input("enter your deltax "))
    func = raw_input("Enter your function as a*x**n + b*x**m.. ex 3*x**3 + 5*x**2 ")
    return trapezoidal(a, b, deltax, lambda x: eval(func))
```

Comment: This is **not** solving the problem. The code is also incorrect, if you don't pass the _optional_ argument `func`, it will crash.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of your source file:

```
import re
```

Change the `raw_input` call to:

```
re.sub(r'([\d])x', r'\1*x', raw_input("Enter a function...")).replace('^', '**')
```

Explanation:
[`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) does a regular-expression replacement. In this case, you're:

- replacing a digit `[\d]`
- *capturing* the digit in group 1 by enclosing it in parenthesis `([\d])`
- followed by `x`

with

- that same digit captured in group 1 `\1`
- followed by an asterisk `*`
- followed by `x`

Finally, we replace all instances of `^` with `**` with a simple [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) call.

---

However, as [tripleee says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23849418/365902), this is not sufficient to actually evaluate the function; this only performs the text-manipulation problem described in your title and in the first part of your question. Actually evaluating the text as a function is a separate problem.

Answer (score 1):

`func` is just a string. You have to `eval` it to execute it as a Python expression. Before you do that, you can perform any string manipulation you like on it.

```
func = raw_input()
func.replace('^', '**')
# TODO: valudation here
f = eval(func)
```

Before you `eval` anything you should verify that it matches your expected input format; otherwise, you have a giant security vulnerability in your code.